# iPad UIPopoverController.PresentFromRect popup positioning

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

iPad - Popup

I have a popup and wish it to be 75% of the height and width of the screen. My screen is a UISplitView.

How is this done with **UIPopoverController.PresentFromRect** ?

I have tried many combos of values, but the results are 'strange'.

Note: I do not wish to use the PresentFromButton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

1) You need o set the size of the popup:

```
myUIPopupController.PopoverContentSize = new SizeF (1024f, 1024f);
```

2) Then set the popup based on a relative frame size:

```
myUIPopupController.PresentFromRect (relativeFrame, this.SplitViewController.View, UIPopoverArrowDirection.Right, true);
```